# How to count number of chars between two chars in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby is there a simple way to count the number of `N`s between the curly brackets in any of the following strings?

`{NNN}YYY{XXX}NNNN{YYY}`

`{XXX}NNN{NN}XXX{YYY}`

`{XXX}NNNN{YY}AAAA{NNNNNN}`

Right now I've got:

```
def count_chars(string)
  string.index('N}') - string.index('{N')
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do the `N`s always appear within a single pairs or curly braces, and without anything else? In other words, does `"{NNN}{XXX}{NNN}"` appear? Does `"{NXNN}{XXX}{YYY}"` appear?

Comment: Things like `"{NXNN}{XXX}{YYY}"` will never appear.

Comment: What about the other one? You need to make that clear within your question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot the difference. I tried to clarify my initial question above. The case is probably easier than you think. Stuff like `{NXY}` will not appear. And there will never be more than one substring containing `N`s.

Comment: If that is the case, then is it necessary at all to mention the curly braces? Will simply counting the `N`s not work, as in VIktor's answer?

Comment: Sorry, I realize I should have mentioned that there may be other characters outside the curly braces. My fault, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with regexes...

```
def count_chars(string)
  string.match(/{(N*)}/)[1].length
end
```

Comment: `string.match(/{(N*)}/)[1].length` will be more specific.

Comment: @yzalavin Thanks!

Comment: Even shorter: `string[/{(N*)}/, 1].length`

Answer (score 4):

Just out of curiosity:

```
'{NNN}{XXX}{YYY}'[/(?<={)N+(?=})/]&.length.to_i
#⇒ 3
```

Comment: Might want to change the `+` to a `*` or safe navigate `&.length` to avoid a `NoMethodError` in the event that `N` does not exist between curly braces at all. Not sure if the intended result would be `0` or `nil` (although I would assume `0` based on the original implementation)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you can't use this :

```
your_string.scan(/N/).count
```

If this isn't what you're looking for please clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: Your solution is indeed simple, but the OP specifically mentioned the `N`s within curly braces, and given the condition (which the OP added later as a response to my comment) that the `N`s appear only once and within a pair of curly braces, I am not sure whether that mattered at all. So it looks like you are right.

Comment: However, in that case, your code is still not as simple as it could be.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I have to admit that my initial question was a little misleading.